# Java How to get ascii char from key code

Tags: java, awt, keyevent

I want to get ascii char from each key that user inputs into JComponent.

```
<JComponentName>.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        char ch = getAsciiCharFromKeyCode(e.getKeyCode());
    }
});

private char getAsciiCharFromKeyCode(int keyCode) {
    // this implementation is what I'm interested in
}
```

When I press 'e' (English 'e') and 'у' (Cyrillic 'u'), I get the same key code (`0x45` or `KeyEvent.VK_E`). Is there some way to implement `getAsciiCharFromKeyCode` function without writing my own hash map like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Character> keyCodeToChar = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
keyCodeToChar.put(KeyEvent.VK_E, 'e');
```

?

Comment: I didn't test it but maybe you are looking for `e.getKeyChar()`.

Answer (score 2):

As Pshermo already mentioned the method you are looking for is e.getKeyChar() however, it is only meaningfull in the method keyTyped as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Your code would modified look like this:

```
<JComponentName>.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char ch = e.getKeyChar();
    }
});
```

Comment: what if I want to detect a fn key pressed. How would I do that

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tutorial [**Oracle: How to Write a Key Listener**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for more information on how to use KeyEvent to grab key info.

*Oracle says:*

> For key-typed events you can obtain the key character value as well as any modifiers used.
>
> **Note:**
> You should not rely on the key character value returned from getKeyChar unless it is involved in a key-typed event.

You may need to set the locale to accept language specific keyboard characters.

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea txtara;
    private JLabel lbl;

    public MyFrame() {
        super();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout();
        this.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ru")); // Russian

        txtara = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        lbl = new JLabel("Key: ");

        txtara.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                lbl.setText("Key: " + e.getKeyChar()); // Show typed character
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
        };

        this.getContentPane().add(txtara, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** This code has not been compiled...